# Rails 4 + Chartkick: Update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I am using [Chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) to draw graphs in my app, but when I try to use the javascript api to update the graph, I get an error in my javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: chart.updateData is not a function(…)
```

My chart is defined and visible on the page and can be queried with `chart`.  Am I missing something obvious, is there something else I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you actually have that chart object first before you want to update the it using `chart = Chartkick.charts['chart_id']` only then can you update that chart using `chart.updateData()`